# Gravação de PList no Device

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou com problemas para fazer a gravação de um Plist em meu app.
Quando testo no simulador ele funciona normalmente, mas no device não salva minhas alterações.

Vi em alguns sites que tenho que criar a minha plist em um lugar acessível para o device, que não é apenas criar na pasta do projeto e sair usando. Mas não entendi direito como fazer isso.

Então a duvida é como faço para já criar uma Plist com dados no aplicativo e permitir que o usuário possa altera-lá?

E caso alguém possa me explicar o conceito disso também fico agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar esse arquivo em tempo de execução no diretório **Documents**, que é onde o seu aplicativo tem permissão de escrita também, pois este é o conceito padrão dos aplicativo no iOS, funcionando em um ambiente *sandbox*. Ou seja, criar o arquivo pelo *Xcode*, seu aplicativo não terá tal permissão.

Para isso, você pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim, quando o aplicativo for instalado:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *strPlist = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arquivo.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:strPlist]) {
    NSArray *arrInfo = /* criar informações da sua plist */;
    [arrInfo writeToFile:strPlist atomically:YES];
}
```

Veja se consegue algo a partir disso. Para melhor entender o ambiente, você pode dar uma lida no **[guia de programação](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)**, na seção **The App Sandbox**.

Comment: Preciso habilitar algo para isso? Quando vou tentar fazer a leitura não acha... o read trás a Plist que criei no projeto...

Comment: Funcionou... eu estava colocando `NSDocumentationDirectory` ao invés de `NSDocumentDiretory`...